# using Java enums or public static fields in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, enums

I'm wondering how in MATLAB you can get a reference to a Java `enum` or static public field. In MATLAB, if you are trying to use Java objects/methods, there are equivalents to Java object creation / method call / etc.:

Java: `new com.example.test.Foo();`

MATLAB: `javaObject('com.example.test.Foo');`

Java: `com.example.test.Foo.staticMethod();`

MATLAB: `javaMethod('staticMethod', 'com.example.test.Foo');`

Java: `SomeEnum e = com.example.test.SomeEnum.MY_FAVORITE_ENUM;`

MATLAB: ?????

Java: `int n = com.example.test.Foo.MAX_FOO`;

MATLAB: ?????

Comment: I assume you can't edit the Java Enum?

Comment: in some cases I can, in some I can't

Comment: this is the flip side to type-safe enums: instead of calling loadWeirdFile('myfile.txt', 1) which has magic numbers but is easy, I call loadWeirdFile('myfile.txt', Options.SKIP_WEIRD_STUFF) which has no magic numbers and is type-safe, but I can't access the SKIP_WEIRD_STUFF constant from my scripting environment. :(

Comment: (that's not the exact function I'm calling, but you get the point)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reference Java enum constants from Matlab using the package.class.FIELD syntax, as with any other static Java field. Let's say you have an enum.

```
package com.example;
public enum MyEnum {
    FOO, BAR, BAZ
}
```

You can get at the enum constants in Matlab using a direct reference. (The Java classes must be in Matlab's javaclasspath, of course.)

```
% Static reference
foo = com.example.MyEnum.FOO

% Import it if you want to omit the package name
import com.example.MyEnum;
foo = MyEnum.FOO
bar = MyEnum.BAR
```

If you want a "dynamic" reference determined at runtime, you can just build a string containing the equivalent static reference and pass it to eval(). This works on almost any Matlab code.

```
% Dynamic reference
foo = eval('com.example.MyEnum.FOO')
```

And if you want to get really fancy, you can use Java reflection to get at all the enumerated constants at run time. Make a thin wrapper to put with your other custom classes to get around quirks with Matlab's classloader. (There's no Matlab javaClass() equivalent; IMHO this is a Matlab oversight.)

```
//In Java
package com.example;
public class Reflector {
    public static Class forName(String className) throws Exception {
        return Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```

Then you can enumerate the constants in Matlab.

```
% Constant enumeration using reflection
klass = com.example.Reflector.forName('com.example.MyEnum');
enums = klass.getEnumConstants();
```

Comment: I think this only works if the enum is not nested in another class. If it is nested, ie the .class has an $ in it, then you may need to use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1846161/1020470) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8032442/1020470).

Answer (score 12):

Inner classes require conversion of '.' to '$' in Matlab.

This may actually due to the way the Java compiler stores internal class objects. It behaves similarly for internal classes (e.g. `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler`). Matlab is not as smart as the JVM to automatically convert these internal '$' into '.'. Therefore, we can't use the regular simple dot-notation in these cases in Matlab, and since '$' is an invalid character in Matlab syntax, we must resort to using the '$' within [`javaObject`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaobject.html), [`javaMethod`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javamethod.html), `awtinvoke` and their relatives. For example:

```
Java: InnerClass c = new com.example.test.SomeEnum.InnerClass;
MATLAB: c = javaObject('com.example.test.SomeEnum$InnerClass')
```

Enums require similar conversion of '.' to '$' in Matlab. But MATLAB's `javaObject` function calls the class constructor, and since enums have no constructor, we get the following error:

> *No constructor with appropriate signature exists in Java class*

Luckily [enum has the builtin method `valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) that we can use with `javaMethod`:

```
Java: SomeEnum e = com.example.test.SomeEnum.MY_FAVORITE_ENUM;
MATLAB: e = javaMethod('valueOf','com.example.test$SomeEnum','MY_FAVORITE_ENUM');
```

Similarly:

```
Java: int n = com.example.test.Foo.MAX_FOO;
MATLAB: n = javaMethod('com.example.test.Foo$MAX_FOO')
```

Static fields can be gotten directly in Matlab using simple dot notation:

```
redColor = java.awt.Color.red;
```

The full list of static fields can be gotten using Matlab's built-in `struct` function:

```
>> staticFields = struct(java.awt.Color.red)
staticFields = 
      white: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
      WHITE: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
  lightGray: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
 LIGHT_GRAY: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       gray: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       GRAY: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
   darkGray: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
  DARK_GRAY: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
      black: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
      BLACK: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
        red: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
        RED: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       pink: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       PINK: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
     orange: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
     ORANGE: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
     yellow: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
     YELLOW: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
      green: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
      GREEN: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
    magenta: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
    MAGENTA: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       cyan: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       CYAN: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       blue: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
       BLUE: [1x1 java.awt.Color]
     OPAQUE: 1
    BITMASK: 2
TRANSLUCENT: 3
```

MATLAB's function `javaObject` may not work if the default constructor is private (hidden), and `javaMethod` probably won't work either. If the class with the static methods is nested you may be out of luck.
For my systray utility on the File Exchange, I used the reflection approach, as described in this post: http://UndocumentedMatlab.com/blog/setting-system-tray-popup-messages/

Credit: edited by [Mark Mikofski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020470/mark-mikofski)

Comment: [@Yair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/233829/yair-altman), I am a huge fan of [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/)! Thanks for making these edits and for giving me credit. I have been working on [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) which has a nested enum `SetupUpstreamMode` for its `org.eclipse.jgit.api.CreateBranchCommand` class and a hidden constructor for its `org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Constants` class, so I had encountered these issues. In case anyone else has these issues, it's good to clarify how to extract the enums & constants in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: 
From [here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk_r13/help/techdoc/matlab_external/ch05ma11.html#46643) it sounds like the regular way would just work. Or are Enums different than other classes with statics for some reason?

Can you call a Java method with parameters?

```
SomeEnum e = com.example.test.SomeEnum.valueOf(SomeEnum.class, "MY_FAVORITE_ENUM")
```

Comment: Wait: no, that wouldn't work. I still have to get a reference to SomeEnum.class which is a public static field. ARGH!

Comment: w/r/t your updated link to "Accessing Private and Public Fields" -- I guess that does work for fields "directly" accessed in MATLAB, e.g. com.example.test.Myfield.FIELD_VAL, I was hoping I could get it based on a dynamic string e.g. fieldval = javaField('com.example.test.Myfield.FIELD_VAL') which doesn't seem like it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same enum issue as the first part of the original question. Putting some information together from posts like those here, I realized that using MATLAB's `javaMethod` function to call `valueOf()` works:

Java: `SomeEnum e = com.example.test.SomeEnum.MY_FAVORITE_ENUM;`

MATLAB: `e = javaMethod('valueOf', 'com.example.test$SomeEnum', 'MY_FAVORITE_ENUM');`

As for the second question, about static variables, I have been able to access public static variables using the normal notation in MATLAB 2009b, so I can't be of much help there. Assuming `MAX_FOO` is declared as a public static int in the Foo class, I can do:

Java: `int n = com.example.test.Foo.MAX_FOO;`

MATLAB: `n = com.example.test.Foo.MAX_FOO;`

Perhaps one of the other answers about dollar signs along with calls to `fooVar.getClass().getFields()` will shed some light.