# Matlab java interop. Use enum values

Tags: java, matlab

I have java enum

```
package com.moc;
public enum MyType {
    s,
    q,
    p,
    none,
}
```

In matlab(2012a) I load appropriate jar, and set

```
a = com.moc.MyType.q;
a = com.moc.MyType.none;
```

It works as well. But when i try to eval

```
a = com.moc.MyType.s;
```

or

```
a = com.moc.MyType.p;
```

I get an exception

```
The class com.moc.MyType has no property or method named 's'.
```

and

```
The class com.moc.MyType has no property or method named 'p'.
```

Why did matlab disallow me to get 's' and 'p' enum values?

P.S.

```
a = com.moc.MyType.q;
a.getClass.getDeclaredField('p')
```

returns

```
public static final com.moc.MyType com.moc.MyType.p
```

**UPDATE**

com.moc.MyType.valueOf('p') works. But question remains relevant for me.

Answer (score 2):

As is listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1846161/544198), you might need to reference it a bit differently. Sometimes Java stores things as `$` instead of `.`, so if you make the call as listed below, it should work.

```
javaObject('com.moc.MyType$q')
```

Comment: Thank you. But why "com.moc.MyType.q" works and "com.moc.MyType.p" not?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly, but I suspect it has to do with being the first enum value. The last one might also work, for the same reason, but everything in the middle won't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, this should work. I'm just guessing, but could you try with upper case enum constants (e.g. com.moc.MyType.P) Maybe there is some sloppy stuff going on that relies on convention.

Answer (score 1):

I would really suspect that this is a configuration error.  (What I used to call a makefile error).  That is, I suspect that the code you are actually loading into Matlab is not linked to the Java code that you are writing, but is an older version.

To confirm/refute this sort of an error, make the smallest change you can which will be visible when you execute.  For instance, change `q` to `qq` and confirm that `a = com.moc.MyType.qq;` works in Matlab.

If it does work, then I'm wrong.
If it does not, than you need to go through your compilation/jar'ing/loading process to see where you have a stale file.

Comment: Thank you. But why "com.moc.MyType.q" works and "com.moc.MyType.p" not?