# java enum in matlab switch case

Tags: java, matlab, enums

I am currently trying to use a Java package in Matlab, which works fine so far. But now I need to do a Switch case in Matlab depending on a Java enum. Here a small example code:

Java:

```
package abc;

class Parser {
    enum FileType {
        UNHANDLED,
        XML,
        BINARY
    }

    public getFileType(){
        this.fileType;
    }

    private FileType fileType;

}
```

In Matlab, I want to do the following:

```
parser = abc.Parser();
Switch (parser.getFileType()) {
      case abc.FileType.BINARY:
            %TODO
      break;
}
```

According to [using Java enums or public static fields in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223795/using-java-enums-or-public-static-fields-in-matlab/1846161#1846161), I can access the enum elements with

```
javaMethod('valueOf', 'abc.Parser$FileType', 'BINARY');
```

but if I use this line in the Switch case:

```
parser = abc.Parser();
Switch(Parser.getFileType()){
      case javaMethod('valueOf', 'abc.Parser$FileType', 'BINARY');
            %TODO
      break;
}
```

I get the error

> ??? SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.

Has anyone a work around to achieve my desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your java doesn't compile. I changed the java to:

```
public class Parser {
    enum FileType {
        UNHANDLED,
        XML,
        BINARY
    }

    public FileType getFileType(){
        return this.fileType;
    }

    private FileType fileType = FileType.XML;

    public Parser(){
    }
}
```

For the switch I just compare the strings wrapped with char().

eg:

```
javaaddpath('/home/shackle/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication50/dist/JavaApplication50.jar')
import abc.Parser

p = Parser();
switch char(p.getFileType().toString())
    case 'BINARY'
            fprintf('type is binary')
      break;

    case 'UNHANDLED'
            fprintf('type is UNHANDLED')
      break;

    case 'XML'
            fprintf('type is XML')
      break;
end
```